# How do I modify Cura's code generation?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code

Cura is generating temperature commands in the wrong order.  I need to swap lines 6 and 7 below so that both the printhead and bed can begin to heat at the same time.

Is this code generation configurable in Cura?

```
5 ;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 2.5.0
6 M190 S60    ; set bed and block
7 M104 S215   ; set printhead, don't block
8 M109 S215   ; set printhead, block
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so by placing this at the top of the start code under machine settings (tested on 2.6.1).

```
M104 S{material_print_temperature}
M190 S{material_bed_temperature}
```